# Setting up DB2 HADR for existing database

Tags: db2, database-administration, high-availability, db2-luw

I have an existing DB2 databases running on DB2 workgroup server 10.1. The database is running fine. Now, we want to setup HADR for those databases.

In addition to following the step by step guide from this URL:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21410648

Is there anything else that I should worry about? Such as increasing the server’s memory or increasing tablespaces, or increase the log?

I know that with HADR we enable log archiving, do we need to increase disk space?

Any other “gotcha” that I should know?

Comment: How much have you planned? Do you plan for manual failovers only?  Are you planning on Automated-Client-Reroute in the case of failover? Before going live rehearse all your *online backups*  and *restores* ((and rollforwards to point in time etc) exhaustively and failovers and failbacks very carefully.  Are you archiving to tape or disk? Suggest you ensure you are at the final V10.1 fixpack (i.e. 6) to ensure you don't hit the fixed bugs relating to HADR.

Comment: Yes, I am planning on automated-client-reroute. I am planning the HADR to another server, we are not going to archive the database to a tape. Thanks a lot for the response though

Comment: If you plan to archive transaction-logs to disk, you will need to have sufficient disk-space to store N days worth of archived-logs where N is the number of days in the past from which you need to recover databases. That's on top of online-backup space.  If the applications use LOAD on the database you will need to ensure that LOAD COPY is effective (there's a Db2-registry variable to convert LOAD into LOAD COPY). If the applications use 'not logged initially' that will need to be removed because it's incompatible with HADR.  Which operating-system runs the Db2-server?

Comment: We are using Red Hat Linux 6

Comment: Do you plan to use TSAMP to manage failovers, or only offer manual takeover ?

Comment: Manual failover